# Creating a function that takes JSON object as an argument

Tags: javascript, html, json, api, object

I want to retrieve information from an API and then create a function that takes the JSOn object as an argument. Then call the function from the method that returns the JSON data and pass in the JSON data. So far i have used fetch() to link to an API:

```
let url = "https://api.magicthegathering.io/v1/cards";

fetch(url)
.then(res => res.json())
.then((out) => {
  console.log("JSON", out);`enter code here`
})
.catch(err => { throw err });
```

Can someone help me figure out how to do the rest?

Comment: How you create a function and deal with arguments is the sort of stuff you should be learning from an introductory JavaScript tutorial, not a Stackoverflow question.

Answer (score -1):

Assuming you have a function named 'handle_data' you can call it like:

```html
<html>
<head>
 <script>

  function handle_data(data) {
   console.log('Data below was printed by handle_data function')
   console.log(JSON.stringify(data))
  }

  function get_json(){
   fetch('https://api.github.com/orgs/nodejs')
   .then(response => response.json())
   .then(data => {
    handle_data(data)
   })
   .catch(error => console.error(error))
  
  }
 </script>
<head>

<body>
 <button type="button" onclick="get_json();">Demo</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: This won't work. `res` is undefined in the scope of the second then handler. Trying to use it will raise an exception.

Comment: Code was modified and tested.

Comment: Thank you for your help! 
I am not supposed to use a button in my HTML for this though.. I want to retrieve the information in the JSON file that I made and make cards from it. 
and the fetch() also doesn´t work unless I use the one I sent earlier. But I will try it out in my code, and see what it does! :)

Comment: The button is just a trigger that activates the fetch code. The essence of the code is to show how to send the data that we got using fetch to other function (handle_data) for doing something useful with it.